# Want help in loop of if and else method in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I wanted the help of you fellow users of Java in making up my computer project. I want to add the loop command for the "if-else"method given in the code below . I am attaching a picture of the design for clearer understanding.
Objective:
To make a calculator which shows how many odd or even numbers I have entered.
Problem:
I am not sure what the loop method is like.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int odd = 0 ;
    int even = 0 ;
    int a = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
    if (a%2==0)
    {
      even++;
      lbleven.setText(""+even);
    }
    else
    {
      odd++;
      lblodd.setText(""+odd);
    }
}
```

[image: The design of my project]

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) *"Problem: I am not sure what the loop method is like."*  I see another problem in that you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: You need to keep the variable `odd` and `even` outside the method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you click on the button, even and odd will set to zero as they are local variables not instance variables, you have to make them instance variables so that they can hold the last value set to them.

```
private int odd;
private int even;

//....
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int a = Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
    if (a%2==0)
    {
      even++;
      lbleven.setText(""+even);
    }
    else
    {
      odd++;
      lblodd.setText(""+odd);
    }
}
```

Or, you can get the odd&even labels text every time and increase them inside your condition.

```
int even= Integer.parseInt(lbleven.getText());
lbleven.setText(""+(++even))
```

Comment: You have to initialize odd and even, otherwise the compiler will complain about use of unassigned variables.

Comment: @Sane: do you mean `private int odd`?

Comment: Yeah, it's just a minor pointer. Your answer is correct otherwise =)

Comment: @Sane: Instance variables or references not need to the assignment, it will be assigned to it's *default* value, `references=null`,`int,double,... =0`, `boolean = false` and so on.